# display tag for table to create multiple links in single column

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I am trying to show a table using display tag.

```
<display:table name="feedList" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="margin-bottom: 0;" requestURI="" id="mFeedList" export="true" pagesize="10">
   <display:column property="feedName" sortable="true" titleKey="Feed" />
   <display:column value="Update" href="updateFeed" media="html" paramId="feedKey" paramProperty="feedKey" titleKey="update"/>
   <display:column value="Clone" href="cloneFeed" media="html"  paramId="feedKey" paramProperty="feedKey" titleKey="clone"/>
</display:table>
```

But I want both the update and clone in a single column  **column name**- ***action***  and **row**- ***Update/Clone*** and the href should also work as same.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<c:url>` inside `<display:column>`

```
 <display:table id="list"   name="display_tbl"                                                                       decorator="checkboxDecorator" form="displ">
 <display:column title="action">    
        <c:url var="url" value="updateFeed">    
          <c:param name="feedKey" value="${list.feedKey}"></c:param> 
        </c:url>
       <a href=${url } title="Update"></a>  

      <c:url var="url1" value="cloneFeed"> 
         <c:param name="cloneFeed" value="${list.cloneFeed}"></c:param> 
      </c:url>  
       <a href=${url1}  title="Clone"></a>

 </display:column>
  </<display:table>
```

Comment: sorry for the late comment, i am passing a `List<feed> feedList` from my action class. The feed object contain a feed key element so it should work something like `<a href=updateFeed?feedKey=2 title="Update" ></a> ` not like `<a href=updateFeed?feedKey=feedKey title="Update" ></a>`

Comment: Actually its like hard coding right? i am passing the feed object from the data base. it will be different each time i retrieve this data. The code in the question takes  'paramId="feedKey" paramProperty="feedKey" ' in that case its works. Your code is fine, but i want the feedkey from the list i pass

Comment: Hi you can get that property value from your list object see my edit